# Screens connected through USB-c HDMI-adapter turn black when playing DRM-content in browser

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-c, drm

As soon as I browse to sites like Netflix or Prime Video and play a movie, some of my external screens turn black. It's always the screens connected via a usb-c HDMI adapter.

Details:

- Laptop: Dell XPS 15 9560
- OS: Windows 10 Professional
- Browser: Chrome, Edge, Firefox or Opera
- Display adapter: Intel(R) HD Graphics 630 / NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050

I tried different usb-c to HDMI adapters, and they have the same problem.
I have the same problem at home as at work (different screens)

I do not have the problem if u use a (really cheap) usb-c to VGA adapter.

Is this a problem specific to Dell of does Windows have some other DRM-protection? Does anybody have the same problem and hopefully a workaround?

Comment: Of course Windows has DRM protection, but in your case it could very well be the adapters, to prevent you from making illegal copies.

Comment: I have the same problem, but my screen turns blue. Also using a USB-C to HDMI adapter. Lenovo Legion 5 Pro, Ryzen 7 5800H + RTX 3070. Have you found a fix yet?

Comment: @zjeffer no, I haven't. My cheap external HDMI-adapters are probably untrusted.